# How can I put an button on right side to FormInput in React Native?

Tags: react-native, textinput

I am using TextInput but unable to set its width
can any one help me out to design a FormInput with a button on right side.
if its join together that will nice

iam using

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row"}}>
                <Ionicons.Button name="md-arrow-round-back" backgroundColor="#FFF" color="#00AEEB" size={25} onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenOne')}/>
                <FormInput autoFocus={true} placeholder="Comment" onChangeText={(comment) => this.setState({comment})} />
                <Ionicons.Button name="md-checkmark" backgroundColor="#0f0" color="#fff" size={25} onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenOne')}/>

            </View>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row"}}>
  <View style={{ width: "10%", height: 40}}>
    <Ionicons.Button name="md-arrow-round-back" style={{ width: "100%"}} backgroundColor="#FFF" color="#00AEEB" onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenOne')}/>
  </View>
  <View style={{ width: "80%", height: 40}}>
    <FormInput autoFocus={true}  placeholder="Comment" onChangeText={(comment) => this.setState({comment})}  />
  </View>
  <View style={{ width: "10%", height: 40, backgroundColor:"#fff", borderRadius: 50}}>
    <Ionicons.Button name="md-checkmark" style={{ width: "100%", borderRadius: 50}} backgroundColor="#548e59" color="#fff"/>
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

TextInput has a [`style` prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#style), within which you can put `width` as a field.

```
<TextInput style={{width: 150, height: 30}} placeholder="Enter stuff here" />
```

To put a button on the right hand side, you can place that `TextInput` inside a `View` component, while giving it these style properties: `{display: flex, flexDirection: row}`:

```
<View style={{display: flex, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <TextInput style={{width: 150, height: 30}} placeholder="Enter stuff here" />
  <Button onPress={this.yourFunction} title="Submit" />
</View>
```

In order to make it so that the width isn't hard-coded, you may make use of the [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions) module like so:

```
import {TextInput, Button, Dimensions} from 'react-native'
const {width} = Dimensions.get('window')

// inside your component
render() {
  return (
    <View style={{display: flex, flexDirection: 'row', width}}>
      <TextInput style={{flex: 0.75, height: 30}} placeholder="Enter stuff here" />
      <Button style={{flex: 0.25}} onPress={this.yourFunction} title="Submit" />
    </View>
  )
}
```

That would give the text field 75% of the width and the button the other 25%.

Comment: width is hard-corded which is not acceptable it should support different device

Comment: @VivekanandPanda I updated the answer to show another possibility based on your requirement.

Comment: means button is not coming on right side its as it as previous.
thanks for your support i solve that problem and post answer also
and you using textInput and the question is for formInput sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 0):

hi @Vivekanand Panda if you whant to not to be hard-coded you can use

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

var { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');
```

it will take the dimensions of the device

```
 <View style={{display: flex, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
     <TextInput style={{width: width-20, height: height}} placeholder="Enter stuff here" />

     ***hear width: width-20  and height: height gives the height and width of the device***

     <Button onPress={this.yourFunction} title="Submit" />
 </View>
```

Comment: you whant the button to be inside of the textinput ?

Comment: no side to it
i solve that thing thanks for your support